# My query works (100+ results.) How do I insert them into a new table?

Tags: sql

my attempt:

`SELECT * into table_joe FROM table_names WHERE username LIKE '%Joe%'`

But this fails saying the new table (table_joe) is an undeclared variable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `INSERT` here, not `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table_joe
SELECT *
FROM table_names
WHERE username LIKE '%Joe%';
```

But note that in general it very advisable to *always* explicitly list out which columns are the target/source in an insert.  So, something like the following is better practice:

```
INSERT INTO table_joe (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table_names
WHERE username LIKE '%Joe%';
```